# Simple Currying in Ruby

Tags: ruby, currying

I'm trying to do some currying in ruby:

```
def add(a,b)
  return a+b
end

plus = lambda {add}
curry_plus = plus.curry
plus_two = curry_plus[2] #Line 24
puts plus_two[3]
```

I get the error

```
func_test.rb:24:in `[]': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
```

from func_test.rb:24:in `'

But if I do

```
plus = lambda {|a,b| a+ b}
```

It seems to work. But by printing plus after the assigning with lambda both ways return the same type of object. What have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
lambda {|a,b| a+ b}
```

Creates a lambda which takes two arguments and returns the result of calling `+` on the first, with the second as its arguments.

```
lambda {add}
```

Creates a lambda which takes no arguments and calls `add` without arguments, which is an error of course.

To do what you want, you should do

```
plus = lambda {|x,y| add(x,y)}
```

or

```
plus = method(:add).to_proc
```

Comment: `:add.to_proc` will not work right. It returns a Proc equivalent to `proc {|receiver, *args| receiver.add(*args)}`. Which means that `:add.to_proc[1,2]` will try to call `1.add(2)` rather than `self.add(1,2)`.

Answer (score 18):

You're on the right track:

```
add = ->(a, b) { a + b }
plus_two = add.curry[2]
plus_two[4]
#> 6
plus_two[5]
#> 7
```

As others have pointed out, the `plus` lambda you defined doesn't take any arguments and calls the `add` method with no arguments.

Answer (score 4):

When you write `lambda {add}`, you're declaring a Proc that takes no arguments and, as its sole action, calls `add` with no arguments. It doesn't turn `add` into a Proc. On the other hand, `lambda {|a,b| a + b}` returns a Proc that takes two arguments and adds them together — since it takes arguments, it's valid to pass arguments to that one.

I think what you want is `method(:add).to_proc.curry`.